# Пишем О - произносим А

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях мы пишем "О", а произносим "а" в слове и почему? Или пишем "О" и произносим "о"? Как это определить? Например, слова: "в  розовой","которые", "домой".

Answer (score 2):

В первой предударной позиции (например, первая буква "о" в слове "домой") звук "о" под действием качественной редукции (изменения безударного гласного) переходит в звук "а", что в речи звучит как краткое "а".

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае речь идет о правописании безударных гласных в корне. На этот счет есть правило: в безударном положении пишется та же гласная, что и в ударом. Таким образом образуются такие буквасочетания как "-оро-", "-оло".
Примеры: *м**оло**ко, к**оро**ва, п**оро**к, б**оро**зда, п**оло**ва*.
Также безударную гласную можно проверить, изменив слово так, чтобы на нее падало ударение: *д**о**мой - д**о**м*.

Answer (score 1):

Есть проверяемые гласные в корне слова, а есть непроверяемые. Либо смотреть в словарь и запоминать, либо подбирать проверочные слова.

Answer (score 1):

Пишем **О** (хоть и говорим **А**), потому что в памяти засели как корни с ударными (проверочными) **О**, так и образы слов. Говорим **А**, а не **О**, потому что акаем, а акаем, потому что это в России — тенденция и норма.

Comment: Вопрос не "почему", а "когда", "в каких случаях".

Comment: "...произносим "а" в слове и почему?" Вопрос так заканчивается. Так я увидел. "Когда" - не вижу.